# Hibernate assigning null to the last record of select?

Tags: java, hibernate

I wanted to create two classes with Hibernate annotations - Book and Bookshelf. Book has a reference to its Bookshelf, Bookshelf holds a list of books it contains. The problem is that when I try to save a new book with a new bookshelf, I get a NullPointerException while trying to access the bookshelf's books.

The interesting thing is that when I re-run the testcase, the record that threw the exception last time gets read but the newly added one crashes the application. What might be the cause of that? Here's the code:

src/main/java/com/mkyong/App.java:

```
 package com.mkyong;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.hibernate.Query;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

 import com.mkyong.pojo.Book;
 import com.mkyong.pojo.Bookshelf;
 import com.mkyong.util.HibernateUtil;


 public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hibernate one to one (Annotation)");
            new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            testWriting(session);

            //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAAlDoAtV7Y
            testReading(session);

            System.out.println("Done");
    }

    private static void testWriting(Session session) {
            session.beginTransaction();

            Bookshelf b2 = new Bookshelf();
            session.save(b2);

            Book b = new Book(b2);

            session.save(b);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    private static void testReading(Session session) {
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Bookshelf");
            List<Bookshelf> bookshelves = q.list();
            System.out.println("The list size is:" + bookshelves.size());
            for (Bookshelf b3 : bookshelves) {
                    System.out.println("b3.id=" + b3.getId());
                    List<Book> books = b3.getBooks();
                    for (Book book : books) {
                            System.out.println(book.getId());
                    }
            }
    }
 }
```

src/main/java/com/mkyong/pojo/Bookshelf.java:

```
 package com.mkyong.pojo;

 import java.util.List;

 import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.FetchType;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.Table;



 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Bookshelf")
 public class Bookshelf implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;

     private List<Book> books;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
     public Integer getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bookshelf")
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
            return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
            this.books = books;
    }
 }
```

src/main/java/com/mkyong/pojo/Book.java:

```
 package com.mkyong.pojo;

 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.FetchType;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
 import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

 import javax.persistence.Id;

 @Entity
 public class Book implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;

    private Bookshelf bookshelf;

    public Book()
    {

    }

    public Book(Bookshelf bookshelf)
    {
            this.bookshelf = bookshelf;  
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
     public Integer getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(name = "bookshelf_id", nullable = false)
     public Bookshelf getBookshelf() {
            return bookshelf;
    }

     public void setBookshelf(Bookshelf bookshelf) {
            this.bookshelf = bookshelf;
    }
 }
```

src/main/java/com/mkyong/util/HibernateUtil.java:

```
 package com.mkyong.util;

 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

 public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
            try {
                    // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                    return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
            // Close caches and connection pools
            getSessionFactory().close();
    }

 }
```

src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <mapping class="com.mkyong.pojo.Book" />
            <mapping class="com.mkyong.pojo.Bookshelf" />

    </session-factory>

 </hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>HibernateExample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>JBoss repository</id>
                    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.8.2</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- MySQL database driver -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.15</version>
            </dependency>

    <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- logback logging framework-->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.28</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.28</version>
            </dependency>

                            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.161</version>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to sift through without knowing where the Exception is thrown from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a null pointer exception because the list of books in the Bookshelf class is never initialized, and no book is ever added to it. It's your responsibility to make the graph of objects consistent. A BookShelf should never have a null list of books. It could have an empty list. And when you create a new book for a given bookshelf, you should also add the book to the bookshelf.

Change your code to:

```
public class Bookshelf implements java.io.Serializable {
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(0);
    ...

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
        book.setBookshelf(this);
    }
}
```

and

```
    private static void testWriting(Session session) {
        session.beginTransaction();

        Bookshelf b2 = new Bookshelf();
        session.save(b2);

        Book b = new Book();
        b2.addBook(b);

        session.save(b);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```